How do I create a 404-NotFound error page in Vuetify3?
I'm new to VueJS and Vuetify as well.
I'm trying to create a 404-page within the pages folder, but it doesn't work from ways I know.
In NextJS for example there are predefined Routes in order to do that (Loading, Error-page, etc.)
Unfortunately, there is no mentioning in the Vuetify documentation on how to do that (except the 404-page itself from the Docs, which is a bit funny I think).
I know how to do that in a regular Vite/VueJS app with a 404-catch-all route.
However, in a vuetify app there is the pages folder and I've assumed that there is a reserved route (something like in NextJS).
I've created a NotFound.vue page component in the pages folder, but that doesn't work.

Vuetify is a component library, it doesn't handle or have anything to do with routing.  The vast majority of vue apps use vue-router (defined routes) or Nuxt (file-system routing) to handle routing.  Which do you have?

Thanks for your attention. I have simply used npm create vuetify@latest which uses vite under the hood I think. I got asked a couple of questions (everything from default + router I picked) I have a pages folder and some other folders and files like router/index.ts, main.ts - everythings works for example, creating a new page in the pages folder works when I add a new file to it. It somehow gets automatically loaded and added to an auto-import file. This is my package.json dependencies: vue, vuetify, @mdi-font, pinia, unplugin-auto-import, unplugin-vue-components, unplugin-vue-router etc.

But adding custom routes to the router messes up the auto-import ends up in auto-import and maintaining routes by hand I think (which I don't want). Thanks for a hint.

unplugin-vue-router is your routing library, it is vue-routers version of file-based routing.  The vuetify command you ran which scaffolded your app added this library and configured it for you, but it is not part of vuetify itself.  The unplugin-vue-router documentation has what you need for a 404 page.

Thank you very much. I appreciate your help a lot.

According to the docs, one has to create a page [...page].vue in the pages folder. This route will match all routes and will display this page when no other routes are matching.
src/pages/[...page].vue
That's it.
